# Rx js - .subscribe is not a function when importing a UnaryFunction from different file

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have the following problem.

Given two files, `intents.ts` and `login.ts` where `intents.ts` contains among others

```
export const loginUiEventsHandler =
    publish((uiEvents: Observable<UiEvents>) =>
        merge(
            uiEvents.pipe(filter(e => e.type === 'EMAIL_LOGIN_CHANGE'), flatMap((e: EmailLoginChange) => validateEmailLogin(e.emailLogin))),
            uiEvents.pipe(filter(e => e.type === 'PASSWORD_CHANGE'), flatMap((e: PasswordChange) => validatePassword(e.password))),
            uiEvents.pipe(filter(e => e.type === 'LOGIN_CLICK'), flatMap((e: LoginClick) => login(e.emailLogin, e.password)))
        )
    )
```

and `login.js` contains among others

```
events
    .pipe(loginUiEventsHandler)
    .subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

When I try to import the function `loginUiEventsHandler` from `intents.ts` into `login.ts` using `import { loginUiEventsHandler } from './intents';` I get the error

`TypeError: selector(...).subscribe is not a function`

However, when I just copy paste the same function into `login.ts` everything seems to work fine.

What do I do wrong? How can I reuse an rxjs UnaryFunction across files.

Please excuse me if this question is obvious, I only just started out using typescript.

Comment: What if you'd explicitly specify the `selector`'s return type as well?: `publish((uiEvents: Observable<UiEvents>): Observable<YourReturnType>  => merge(...))`

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think this is a type issue. I removed all type annotations and converted the file to a regular js file and still get the error. I think this must have something to do with loginUiEventsHandler not being imported as a function